# Tool for monitoring table churn in MS SQL Server

Tags: monitoring, sql-server

I am looking for Desktop or Web based MS SQL Server monitoring tools, that runs on Windows Server 2008 ~ 2012, my budget is around $3000, who have this capability:

1. Able to monitor how many data rows added to a table, for the entire table in a database and all the of the database in the SQL server
2. Able to monitor how many data rows are updated or deleted, like wise as above
3. Standard performance monitoring, such as detecting expensive queries, fragmented index, etc.

Currently, I am using manual methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

1. **Able to monitor how many data rows added to a table:** keep using manual methods.
2. **Able to monitor how many data rows are updated or deleted:** keep using manual methods.
3. **Standard performance monitoring:** any of [these](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/sql-server-monitoring-tools/) . They all provide a free trial so you can find the most suitable for you according to your budget. They all provide detecting expensive queries, fragmented index, etc.

**EDIT:** watch this video at [7:53](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcF2sG5J4sk&t=474s):

```
sp_BlitzIndex @Mode = 2, @SortOrder = rows
```

That will give you a list of all the objects in the databases sorted by the number of rows.

There is also a new feature that came out lately: [Change Tracking in your SQL Database](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/don-t-let-change-pass-you-by-get-started-with-change-tracking-in/ba-p/3801442?emcs_t=S2h8ZW1haWx8ZGlnZXN0X25vdGlmaWNhdGlvbnxMR1RFQ083WEdUSVVPRXwtMXxPVEhFUlN8aEs).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll look into it

Comment: What is expected is a review of the software you recommendation, not a link to a list store somewhere else.